# Pass data from Tableview to Tableview Detail

Tags: ios, json, uitableview, swifty-json

I have two tableviews .The first is going to display 6 cities  and the second (detail tableview) will display a detail based on the cell selected on the first tableview .I create 6 arrays for every city .Every Time the user select a city on the first tableview  , i want to take the corresponding array to populate the second view controller .So my question is how do i  achieve it with prepareforsegue .

```
 //First tableview as initial view 



 import UIKit
 import  Alamofire
 import SwiftyJSON

 class LandingPageTableViewController: UITableViewController {

@IBOutlet var tableview: UITableView!


//predfined array to to holde the data below

var city = [String]()
var subtitle = [String]()
var image = [String]()

//arrays to hold avaible buildings in the city

var brickellBuildings     = [[String:AnyObject]]()//
var miamiBuilBuildings    = [[String:AnyObject]]()
var miamiBeachBuildings   = [[String:AnyObject]]()//
var coconotGroveBuildins  = [[String:AnyObject]]()//
var corolGbalesBuilduings = [[String:AnyObject]]()
var dowtownMiamiBuildings = [[String:AnyObject]]()//
var southBeachBuildings   = [[String:AnyObject]]()



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between   presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()

    tableview.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    tableview.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
    tableview.dataSource =   self
    tableview.delegate   =   self


city = ["Miami","Brickell","Miami Beach","Down town Miami","South Beach","Corol Gables","Coconut Grove"]


    subtitle = ["The fab and glam life "," Condos on the highrise","Don't call a comeback","Come on feel the noise ","Push it to the limit","Push it to the limit","Push it to the limit"]

    image = ["Miami","brickell","miami_beach","downtown_miami","south_beach","coral_gables","coconut_grove"]



}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)

    runRequestForbrickell()
    runRequestForMiamiBeach()
    runRequestForcocotGrove()
    runRequestForMiami()
}





   func runRequestForbrickell() {

    Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://android.goidx.com/condos/?tag=brickell&user_id=4").validate().responseJSON { response in

        if let value  = response.result.value {
            let json = JSON(value)

            if let resData = json.arrayObject {

                self.brickellBuildings = resData as! [[String:AnyObject]]

                // print(resData)
            }

            if self.brickellBuildings.count > 0 {

                self.tableview.reloadData()
            }
            }
            }
            }

     func runRequestForMiamiBeach() {


    Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://android.goidx.com/condos/?tag=south beach&user_id=4").validate().responseJSON { response in

        if let value  = response.result.value {
            let json = JSON(value)

            if let resData = json.arrayObject {

                self.miamiBeachBuildings = resData as! [[String:AnyObject]]

                // print(resData)
            }

            if self.miamiBeachBuildings.count > 0 {

                self.tableview.reloadData()
            }

           }
           }
           }


     func runRequestForcocotGrove() {

Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://android.goidx.com/condos/?tag=coconut%20grove&user_id=4").validate().responseJSON { response in

    if let value  = response.result.value {
        let json = JSON(value)

        if let resData = json.arrayObject {

            self.coconotGroveBuildins = resData as! [[String:AnyObject]]

            // print(resData)
        }

        if self.coconotGroveBuildins.count > 0 {

            self.tableview.reloadData()
        }
       }
      }
      }



       func runRequestForMiami() {

Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://android.goidx.com/condos/?tag=downtown miami&user_id=4").validate().responseJSON { response in

    if let value  = response.result.value {
        let json = JSON(value)

        if let resData = json.arrayObject {

            self.miamiBuilBuildings = resData as! [[String:AnyObject]]

            // print(resData)
        }

        if self.miamiBuilBuildings.count > 0 {

            self.tableview.reloadData()
        }
        }
        }
        }



override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if let identifier = segue.identifier {

        switch identifier {


        case "showbuildings":
            let buildingdDetailVC = segue.destinationViewController as! CtiesTableViewController

            if let indexpath = self.tableview.{


            }

        default: break



        }
        }
        }


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
   }

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return city.count
    }


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Celllanding", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! LandingTableViewCell


    let holder_city = city[indexPath.row]
    let holder_subtitle = subtitle[indexPath.row]
    cell.citynamelabel.text? = holder_city
    cell.descriptionHolder.text? = holder_subtitle


    cell.imageCity.image = UIImage(named: image[indexPath.row])

    return cell
     }



/*
// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    // Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return true
}
*/

/*
// Override to support editing the table view.
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .Delete {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    } else if editingStyle == .Insert {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }    
     }
*/

/*
// Override to support rearranging the table view.
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, moveRowAtIndexPath fromIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {

      }
*/

/*
// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    // Return false if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return true
    }
*/

/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
     }
*/


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 300.0
     }



     }









  //Second tableview as a detail tableview 





    import UIKit
    import  Alamofire
    import SwiftyJSON

    class CtiesTableViewController: UITableViewController {

@IBOutlet var tableview: UITableView!


var images = [String] ()



    // Strings to store the data passed from the first tableview 
    var datareceiver1: String = "" 
    var datareceiver2: String = ""
    var datareceiver3: String = ""
    var datareceiver4: String = ""
    var datareceiver5: String = ""

    // array of dictionary to append the data received from first tableview 
    var Data1 = [[String:AnyObject]]() //Array of dictionary
    var Data2 = [[String:AnyObject]]() //Array of dictionary
    var Data3 = [[String:AnyObject]]() //Array of dictionary
    var Data4 = [[String:AnyObject]]() //Array of dictionary
    var Data5 = [[String:AnyObject]]() //Array of dictionary
    var Data6 = [[String:AnyObject]]() //Array of dictionary


func refresh(sender:AnyObject)
{
    // Updating your data here...

    self.tableView.reloadData()
    self.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
}


    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.

    self.refreshControl?.addTarget(self, action: "refresh:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
    refreshControl!.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
    refreshControl!.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()



        }


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

       }



    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {


    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    tableview.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    tableview.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
    tableview.dataSource =   self
    tableview.delegate   =   self


    self.tableview.rowHeight = 300.0



    }


// MARK: - Table view data source

     override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    //print(uniq(data).count)
   //return (uniq(data1).count)

    return Data.count

}


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PlacesTableViewCell

    // Configure the cell...




    return cell
    }


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare a variable to hold the array to be passed and `override` the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method of `UITableViewDelegate` in the first `TableViewController`

```
var arrayToBePassed: YourType?
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    switch indexPath.row {
    case 0:
         arrayToBePassed = yourArray

    default:
         break
    }
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showbuildings", sender: self)
}
```

This will invoke the `prepareForSegue` method. Now declare a `var` of the array type you mentioned, in the second `UITableViewController` and modify `prepareForSegue`

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
   switch identifier {
        let buildingdDetailVC = segue.destinationViewController as! CtiesTableViewController
        buildingdDetailVC.arrayInSecondTVC = arrayToBePassed

    default:
        break
    }
}
```

PS: Please make sure you are not `overriding` `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` as it is a common mistake made.

Comment: when you say your array . Are you talking about the array in the secondview ?

Comment: `yourArray` is the array holding the details of the row you select in first `UITableViewController`. In `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` it is copied into another common array of same type which is `arrayToBePassed`. `arrayInSecondTVC` is an array to be declared in the second `TableViewController` class and in `prepareForSegue` of first controller you will populate this array with detail of the row selected.